# store.each not working

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am working on extjs3.2 Grid.I have a store  as explained in below link

http://loianegroner.com/2010/09/extjs-spring-mvc-3-and-hibernate-3-5-crud-datagrid-example/

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
                    id : 'user',
                    proxy : proxy,
                    reader : reader,
                    writer : writer, // <-- plug a DataWriter into the store
                    url: 'aaa/view.action',
                    remoteSort: true,


                    autoSave : false
                // <-- false would delay executing create, update, destroy
                // requests until specifically told to do so with some [save]
                // buton.
                });
```

But when i use store each its not working

```
store.each(function(r) {
            alert(r.get('col'));
               })
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: i am not getting any error message

Comment: and you get no alert? or what is not working? does the store contain records (is `store.getCount()` greater 0?)

Comment: yes in alert i am not getting anything

Comment: and my second question?

Comment: if i render same store in grid its showing record

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50814/discussion-between-user3106347-and-jandalf)

Comment: but maybe at the time where you use `store.each()` there are no records. please insert `alert(store.getCount())` before the each function.

Comment: Since you get empty alert I presume there are records. I think the question is, did you add 'col' in list of fields in record definition?